# Frame not faced for BB. Strip the paint or leave as-is?

Tags: frames, bottom-bracket

So I just got my new frame from the LBS. They were supposed to face the frame, but only faced the head tube (hopefully, can't check it since the headset is already installed.).

Sadly, they didn't face the BB shell.

I'm tired of bringing my bikes to LBS and getting them in a worst shape than they were before (tried 4 different), so I'm not gonna go back for facing.

I'm planning to install a square taper BB. **I understand there's nothing like a properly faced BB shell**, but no LBS here in Belgium seems to be willing to do that kind of stuff, saying "it's not necessary". So, which of the two following option is the best (or least worse, as it happens)?

1. keep the frame as-is and install the BB
2. strip the paint with a knife?

Comment: The LBS should have done that. Take it back and let them do it with the right tools!

Comment: I think my answer to your previous question [here](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/29629/remove-paint-from-the-head-tube) covers this -- get them to do it.

Comment: Agree. But based on the fact that they even put a wrong sized seat post in the frame, I'm quite afraid they would damage it even more...

Comment: You already asked how to remove the paint in a separate question.  If you can't find a good local bike shop is not a problem this site can fix.

Comment: Indeed, I can't find one. That's why I'm asking, among the two options, which one is the best (or less worse, as I understand so well).

Comment: If the LBS did not properly prep the frame then return it. Why would you go down a path of a custom build if you are not going to do it right?  And that link that you misquoted in your last post has the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things at play here:

1. The actual issue of the bottom bracket facing
2. The bike shop doing poor work.

With common square taper BBs, you are pretty much looking entirely at problem 2. With a cartridge bearing square taper BB, it's not absolutely necessary that the bottom bracket is perfectly faced. Most decent quality frames, even unfaced, have a shell that is consistent enough for cartridge bottom brackets though. Still, having the shell faced is a good thing to do, and if you are using other bottom brackets styles, such as a hollowtech type, then it is absolutely necessary.

However, if the shop said they were going to face it, you paid for them to face it, but they didn't, then they obviously need to do what they said they were going to do. Putting the wrong sized seatpost in is also a seriously bad move.

So really, your problem isn't one of whether to strip the paint or not, but is one of you need to find a better shop with better worksmanship.